# Having a hard time using booth's algorithm to multiply two negative numbers

Tags: algorithm, binary, multiplication

Both numbers are in two's complement form

1101*1100

This is my work but I am getting an answer that is way off I'm not sure if its the adding part or the shifting but I know the criteria of when to shift and not shift so I guess it is the adding but I'm not sure whats going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the third step when you do A-M then shift. In your calculations you are doing A+M, not A-M. Regardless of whether M is positive or negative, when you subtract, you take the 2's complement and then add. In essence, you need to do A + (-M). Taking the 2's complement of M gives 0101, so:

If A = 0000, M=1011:

A+M : 0000(0) + (1011)(-5) = 1011 (-5)

A-M : 0000(0) - (1011)(-5) = 0000(0) + 0101(5) = 0101 (5)

Answer (score -1):

**this is my approach.**
IF u are considering (-9)*(-4).
then just invert 2's complement.
i.e

- first subtract 1

then

- again complement the result.

see ur result is 11101100
now sub 1

- step1: 11101100 - 1 = *11101011*
- step2: invert (*11101011*) and    result is 00010100

which is 36 in binary

the above is reverse 2's complement.
And try it for different question and it work.
Actually it is the right method to do, i think i have read it in some book actually i don't remember yet.
Hope it works